# Highchart without padding inside the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

is it possible to have an linechart without the padding left and right? So that the line would be edge to edge, just like in the Design?

[image: Preview]

At the moment it looks like that

[image: Demo]

```
chartOptions: {
chart: {
  type: 'spline',
  spacingBottom: 0,
},
title: null,
legend: {
  enabled: false
},
credits: {
  enabled: false,
},
tooltip: {
  split: true,
  pointFormat: '{point.y} {series.name}',
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    shadow: true,
  },
},
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  tickWidth: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  crosshair: true,
},
yAxis: {
  visible: false,
},
series: [
  {
    name: 'Bookings',
    data: [43, 44, 43, 42, 42, 41, 42, 43, 45, 44, 42, 43],
  },
  {
    name: 'EUR',
    data: [143, 144, 143, 142, 142, 141, 142, 143, 145, 144, 142, 143],
  },
],
```

},

Comment: First [check](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you please link your html and css

Comment: Unfurtonelly no, cause we have it on our dev Server, wich is not online for everyone

Comment: then post snippets or screenshots of the code

Comment: I updated the question with some code examples

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible by adding to "xAxis" configuration object, params "min" and "max", which determines minimum and maximum value of the axis. However, no exactly in your case, because there isn't enough data in series of this chart ( you don't specify the data before January and after December, therefore chart has start point and an end point ).

Here is a piece of configuration code based on yours:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul','Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', ''],
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    crosshair: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 12
},

series: [
    {
     name: 'Bookings',
     data: [39, 43, 44, 43, 42, 42, 41, 42, 43, 45, 44, 42, 43, 48],
    },
    {
     name: 'EUR',
     data: [141, 143, 144, 143, 142, 142, 141, 142, 143, 145, 144, 142, 143, 148],
    },
],
```

I added two more categories ( one before 'Jan' and one after 'Dec' ), and two more data positions for both of series objects. Due to set min and max params, chart shows the range only from between this points.

Finally, You should set spacing like this:

```
chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    spacing: [0,0,10,0]
},
```

Lets look on the live working below:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/vjr90bhk/)

Best regards!